# Approximate regular expression with a constraint on percentage of errors

Tags: regex, percentage, fuzzy, approximate

The approximate regular expression such as the one at https://pypi.org/project/regex/ allows the use of a threshold on the total number of errors (insertions, deletions, substitutions). 
   For example `(?:foo){e<=2}` allows matches with at most two errors. 
   The threshold here is specified as the total number of errors. Is there any package that allows me to specify **percentage** of errors, instead of total errors?

Comment: Just FYI: you need to use `(?:foo){e<=2}` to make the fuzzy quantifier apply to the whole sequence.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! I have corrected this in the question. Do you know if there is anyway to do something like `(?:foot){E<=0.2}` where {E<=0.2} means the percentage of error is less than 0.2

Comment: No idea. Please also note that [*"questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)